# How to drop the first digit in phone number in php

Tags: php, laravel

I want to drop the first digit in phone number in php (for laravel framework). For example, if the user enter 05030123456, I want to get +2335030123456 into the database. That is, if my phone column in the database is phone_number, I will normally have the code in the controller look like this:

`$user->phone_number = $request->phone`

So, how can I treat `$request->phone` so it send +2335030123456 to the database for `$user->phone_number` instead of 05030123456.

Comment: That sounds like pretty straight forward string manipulation. What is the real question here? Are you asking for a more "laravel" way to do this? Or do you just want other people to solve your problems?

Comment: Not really. just normal PHP or if there is way peculiar to laravel. Just to drop the first zero is fine. Ib can add the +233. Thanks

Comment: do you want to add '+233' in every requested phone number ? If yes then your code will be $user->phone_number = '+233'.$request->phone ( column type should be varchar id any symbol  )

Comment: Yes every request. But will this code: $user->phone_number = '+233'.$request->phone +23305030123456 ? I don't want the zero. I need return +2335030123456

Comment: Okay. if you remove first zero then use substr ($str,1) LIKE :  '+233'.substr($request->phone, 1). O/P will be +2335030123456.  Hope it will be help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want predefined '+233' then below code will be help you.

```
$user->phone_number = '+233'.substr($request->phone, 1);
```

So, your output will be : +2335030123456.

Answer (score 1):

use string manipulation their is `Str` class in Laravel it's very useful

```
\Str::replaceFirst('0','+233', $request->phone)
```

Comment: OK, I will try this to see if it works and I can also read more about it. Thanks.

Comment: This [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#strings-method-list) will help you

Comment: Won't this solution have undesirable effect if the phone number has other zeroes in it?

Comment: That is true I updated my question

Comment: I did not try this but I believe it will work.